# Copying field data from an existing record to new record, then inserting more values

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I copy and insert data from one record to another new record with this code using a button click command from my webpage:

```
Using cmd3 As New OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO tblPalletRecords (PackDay, 
Grade, Grower, HarvestDate, Status, Quality) SELECT PackDay, Grade, Grower, 
HarvestDate, Status, Quality FROM tblPalletRecords WHERE ID = @x", conn)
cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@x", txbID.Text)

conn.Open()
cmd3.ExecuteScalar()
conn.Close()

End Using
```

Everything works, but now I want to insert into Two other fields in this record: PalletNumber and CaseCount.  The values that I want to insert for PalletNumber field and CaseCount field are found in textboxes on the webpage.

What is the most efficient way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can let them be the parameter in `insert into ... select` of `select` values.

the SQL will look like

```
INSERT INTO tblPalletRecords (PackDay, Grade, Grower, HarvestDate, Status, Quality,PalletNumber,CaseCount) 
SELECT PackDay, Grade, Grower, HarvestDate, Status, Quality,@PalletNumber,@CaseCount
FROM tblPalletRecords 
WHERE ID = @x
```

Vb full code

```
Using cmd3 As New OleDbCommand("
INSERT INTO tblPalletRecords (PackDay, Grade, Grower, HarvestDate, Status, Quality,PalletNumber,CaseCount) 
SELECT PackDay, Grade, Grower, HarvestDate, Status, Quality,@PalletNumber,@CaseCount
FROM tblPalletRecords WHERE ID = @x", conn)

cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@x", txbID.Text)
cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PalletNumber", PalletNumber.Text)
cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CaseCount", CaseCount.Text)

conn.Open()
cmd3.ExecuteScalar()
conn.Close()
End Using
```